# The collection argument 'properties' must contain at least one element. when using dotnet ef

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, mariadb, .net-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have two very simple tables

```
CREATE TABLE `site` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `program` (
  `Contract` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SiteId` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Contract`),
  KEY `SiteId` (`SiteId`),
  CONSTRAINT `SiteId` FOREIGN KEY (`SiteId`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

There is a FK on the SiteId field of the program table.

When I try and generate my models using

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "constring" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -f -o "Models"  -d
```

It returns the error

```
The collection argument 'properties' must contain at least one element.
```

Removing the FK the model generates fine. What is wrong with my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was resolved with version [2.0.0-rtm-10057](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/2.0.0-rtm-10057).